# WSDL elements relationships

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I am reading through the web to understand clearly the WSDL and the elements composing WSDL.
Is there a pictorial representation of how the WSDL elements namely
`definitions, types, portTypes, port, message, operation, binding and services` are related?

For example I understand that if I want to describe a service say calculator; it can do several operations say add, substract, divide and multiply.

So I define portType (calculator) abstract entity that identifies the operations it can perform (add, substract, divide and multiply).
I can then have a binding element that describes how this interface is implemented over different concrete protocols (HTTP, SMTP etc.)

> 1> So can I have 2 bindings that specify same "calculator" portTypes
>   one using HTTP and another using SMTP? Can a single WSDL define
>   multiple services (say calculator, unit converter etc)?
>
> 2> Is there a pictorial/descriptive representation of co-relationship
>   between the WSDL elements (definitions, types, portTypes, port,
>   message, operation, binding and services)?
>
> 3> If my portType describes the operations involved in a service; how
>   is it different then the service element?

Here are the web links I am trying to formulate my ideas from. These are very helpful but I am trying to get a clear picture of how the WSDL components are related.

References:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx
http://khanna111.com/wordPressBlog/2013/11/21/248/
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_wsdl_documents.asp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1> So can I have 2 bindings that specify same "calculator" portTypes one using HTTP and another using SMTP?
```

Yes.

```
Can a single WSDL define multiple services (say calculator, unit converter etc)?
```

Yes you can. But both services will be published on different URL, so what will be the point?

```
2> Is there a pictorial/descriptive representation of co-relationship between the WSDL elements (definitions, types, portTypes, port, message, operation, binding and services)?
3> If my portType describes the operations involved in a service; how is it different then the service element?
```

I have described these in this post, you can refer
[WSDL Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891198/details-on-wsdl-ports/20896599#20896599)